# How can I configure ASP.NET MVC routing in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Got a question about routing in ASP.NET MVC.

I want to have nice URLs in my app and that's why I use routing like

```
context.MapRoute(
     name: "ManageProducts_Home",
     url: "Eshop/ManageProducts/{eshopId}",
     defaults: new { controller = "ManageProducts", action = "Home", AreaName = "Eshop" }
);
```

which gives me nice urls like

```
https://localhost:44381/Eshop/ManageProducts/22
```

which is great!

Then I have another route:

```
context.MapRoute(
     name: "ManageProducts_AddProduct",
     url: "Eshop/ManageProducts/AddProduct/{eshopId}/{topCategoryId}",
     defaults: new { controller = "ManageProducts", action = "AddProduct", AreaName =  "Eshop" }
);
```

Which produces this URL:

```
https://localhost:44381/Eshop/ManageProducts/AddProduct/22/1
```

Ok, so far so good.

But on the second page (`AddProduct`), I need to refresh some partial view via AJAX which I call like this

```
$("._SelectCategory").load("/Eshop/ManageProducts/_SelectCategory", { categoryId: categoryId });
```

There is of course an action `_SelectCategory` in the controller which takes a parameter `categoryId`.

The problem is, this call is caught by the first routing and fails with exception missing `eshopId` in action Home, meaning this call doesn't go to the default routing I have there

```
context.MapRoute(
     "Eshop_default",
     "Eshop/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I need some advice how to configure the routing in view `AddProduct` works the ajax call.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use a Web API Empty Controller and give your routes there that is more efficient
eg:
in ManageProducts controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Eshop/ManageProducts/{eshopId}")]
```

In your Startup.cs configure meathod
add this:   app.UseMvc();